ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications in React

I currently have a project (a code debugger) that has 2 monaco editors side by side. there is a button bar that hides one of the editors and resizes the other one to fill the screen. Initially the page works fine. this error appears when i revert back to side by side. Even then I can dismiss the error and continue.

ERROR
ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.
at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:104767:58)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:104786:7

import "./Options.css";
import "./MainView.css";
import ButtonBar from "../Button/Button_Bar.js";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import ApiHandler from "../../ApiHandler/ApiHandler";
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { Box, IconButton, CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import { IoMdSend } from "react-icons/io";

function MainView() {
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const [codeResult, setCodeResult] = useState("");
  const [commentResult, setCommentResult] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const inputsRef = useRef(null);
  const outputsRef = useRef(null);

  const [mode, setMode] = useState("Side-by-Side"); // Default mode

  // Debounce function
  const debounce = (func, wait) => {
    let timeout;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        func(...args);
      }, wait);
    };
  };

  const handleModeChange = useCallback(
    debounce((buttonName) => {
      setMode(buttonName);
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (inputsRef.current) {
          inputsRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
        }
        if (outputsRef.current) {
          outputsRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
        }
      },100 );
    }, 200), // Adjust debounce time if necessary
    []
  );

  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const formatCodeToJSON = (code) => {
        return JSON.stringify({ code });
      };
      const formattedCode = formatCodeToJSON(code);
      const response = await ApiHandler.submitCode(formattedCode, comment);
      var correctedCode = response["data"]["corrected_code"];
      if (correctedCode.startsWith("```python")) {
        correctedCode = correctedCode.split("```");
      }
      setCodeResult(correctedCode);
      setCommentResult(response["data"]["comment"]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = debounce(() => {
      if (inputsRef.current) {
        inputsRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
      }
      if (outputsRef.current) {
        outputsRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
      }
    }, 100);

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div>
        <ButtonBar handleModeChange={handleModeChange} />
      </div>

      <div className="codefixer-area">
        <div
          ref={inputsRef}
          className={`inputs ${mode === "Buggy" ? "fullscreen" : mode === "Side-by-Side" ? "side-by-side" : "hide"}`}
        >
          <div className="rounded-editor">
            <Editor
            
              height="430px"
              language="python"
              theme="vs-dark"
              value={code}
              onChange={(value) => setCode(value)}
              options={{
                scrollbars: "none",
                inlineSuggest: true,
                fontSize: "14px",
                marginBottom: "8px",
                formatOnType: true,
                autoClosingBrackets: true,
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <Box className="chat-input">
            <textarea
              type="text"
              value={comment}
              onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                  handleButtonClick();
                }
              }}
              placeholder="Type additional comments here..."
              rows="4"
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                whiteSpace: "pre-wrap",
                overflowWrap: "break-word",
                border: "none",
                outline: "none",
                resize: "none",
              }}
            />
            <IconButton onClick={handleButtonClick}>
              <IoMdSend />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
        </div>

        <div
          ref={outputsRef}
          className={`outputs ${mode === "Corrected" ? "fullscreen" : mode === "Side-by-Side" ? "side-by-side" : "hide"}`}
        >
          {loading ? (
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" height="100%">
              <CircularProgress />
            </Box>
          ) : (
            <div className="rounded-editor">
              <Editor
                height="430px"
                language="python"
                width="100%"
                theme="vs-dark"
                value={codeResult}
                onChange={(value) => setCodeResult(value)}
                options={{
                  readOnly: true,
                  inlineSuggest: true,
                  fontSize: "14px",
                  marginBottom: "8px",
                  formatOnType: true,
                  autoClosingBrackets: true,
                }}
              />
            </div>
          )}
          <Box className="chat-input">
            <textarea
              value={commentResult}
              rows="4"
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                resize: "none",
                boxSizing: "border-box",
                border: "none",
                outline: "none",
                resize: "none",
              }}
              readOnly
            />
          </Box>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainView;


.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 11%;
}

.codefixer-area {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.inputs,
.outputs {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.inputs.hide,
.outputs.hide {
  display: none;
}

.inputs.fullscreen,
.outputs.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.inputs.side-by-side,
.outputs.side-by-side {
  width: 50%;
  
}

.rounded-editor {
  border-radius: 20px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.chat-input {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(61, 59, 77, 0.3);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

textarea {
  background-color: transparent;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 5px solid #1e1e1e;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
  color: white;
}


I tried various methods like using a debounce method to fix it but nothing works.
